Does Every Cubic Graph Always Have a 2-factor?
If yes, could you give me are reference for the result?
If not, please provide a counter example.

Different parts of the world use different names for things in Graph Theory. Can you explain what exactly you mean by 2-factor?

A spanning graph which is 2-regular.

OK. Thanks. Understood now.

It seems I found a counterexample. In this cubic graph there is no cycle containing $v$. So the graph has no 2-factor.

